# Recorrer Xml Con PHP

Tags: php, xml

Buenas como puedo hacer para recorrer un xml con php he utilizado simpleXml. Pero no me se como acceder a un tercer nodo hijo por ejemplo:

```
<Factura>
     <Cliente>
           <Nombre>Juan</Nombre>
     </Cliente
</Factura>
```

Ocuparía leer el valor del Nodo Nombre...Saludos.

Comment: Muestra como accedes al xml y hasta dónde llegas, si accedes a nodos superiores sería $xml->Factura->Cliente->Nombre.

Answer (score 2):

logré solucionar con

```
$Xml=simplexml_load_string($Factura['StrXml']);
foreach ($Xml->Cliente as $nodo) 
    {
    echo $nodo->Nombre;
 }
```

Saludos...